# Fortran code called by R package causes segfault crash on Linux only

Tags: r, linux, docker, fortran, gfortran

I am trying to use the [smwrQW](https://github.com/USGS-R/smwrQW) R package. I can get it to work on Windows machines (`example("censReg", "smwrQW")`). However, running the same code on a Linux machine causes me an instant segfault. I believe I have tracked the error to the following [line](https://github.com/USGS-R/smwrQW/blob/master/R/censReg.fit.R#L33).

You should be able to reproduce this behavior with Docker and the following set of commands:

```
docker pull rocker/tidyverse
docker run -it rocker/tidyverse /bin/bash

sudo apt-get install ed

Rscript -e "devtools::install_github('USGS-R/smwrBase')"
Rscript -e "devtools::install_github('USGS-R/smwrGraphs')"
Rscript -e "devtools::install_github('USGS-R/smwrStats')"
Rscript -e "devtools::install_github('USGS-R/smwrQW')"

Rscript -e "example('censReg', package = 'smwrQW')"
```

Is the problem caused by a mismatch between the Docker version of gfortran (6.3.0) and the version in RTools? See http://www.thecoatlessprofessor.com/programming/rcpp-rcpparmadillo-and-os-x-mavericks-lgfortran-and-lquadmath-error/#the-solution

I have come across two puzzling quirks. First, if I set a breakpoint (`browser()`) just prior to the line linked above (and step through manually) there is no error. Second, the travis build appears to be passing.

Comment: I think you need to slow down, and sort out which operating system you are looking at how:  A) There is no RTools/travis.  Rtools is for Windows.  Travis is generally using an ancient Ubuntu version (but there are ways to get current gcc/g++/gfortran.  B) James' writeup is for macOS and has little bearing on your other issues.

Comment: Also: experience teaches us that most segfaults are real bugs. You may have gotten lucky before on Windows.

Comment: The behavior on Windows is consistent (I have tried on multiple machines and on multiple occasions). I agree, it is likely to be a bug. Just looking for some clues as to why travis-Linux and Windows commands pass but not local or Docker commands.

Comment: By "slow down" and "segfaults are real bugs" do you mean that it is likely to be an issue with the fortran code itself rather than a compiler/configure issue?

Comment: Possibly. I would try to drill down, either with `gdb` or copious use of print statements, and see _where_ it segfauls and _which_ values cause it.  It could of course be "merely" a configuration issue.  I can't tell, and I don't have time to install five large packages just to play -- sorry.

Comment: If you haven't matched gfortran compiler version with the gcc and gfortran library version that could be a problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran gdb following the instructions at http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/src.html#src-debugging:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
nortest (censflag=..., df=0, llr=0, nobsc=24, sresid=..., plev=0, 
    ierr=<error reading variable: Cannot access memory at address 0x0>)
    at NORTEST.f:75
75        IERR = 0
```

Turns out that one of the variables (`IERR`) expected by the `NORTEST` subroutine wasn't being passed. Fixed the assignment and no more error! Thanks Dirk!

**Update**

I have no idea why the old code runs on Windows:

```
CALL NORTEST(CENSFLAG,DF,LLRAML,NOBSC,SRESID,PLEVAML)
```

when `NORTEST` requires an additional argument:

```
SUBROUTINE NORTEST(CENSFLAG,DF,LLR,NOBSC,SRESID,PLEV,IERR)
```

Comment: Good that you found the error. Please report it upstream as well so the next user won't run into the same issue!

Comment: Where does this incorrect call happen? In your own code or in the package?

Comment: @VladimirF it happens in the package. Do older Fortran compilers not require that all parameters be specified?

Comment: Yes, that has always been required.